# how to write data to xml file in qt

Tags: xml, qt

I need to create xml file in qt. i take data from Qstring. I look an example that create txt file from qstring but when i change the file extension to ".xml" it didn't create xml file. it just change extention. I'm newbie how can i do this here is my code

```
 QFile xmlfile("test.xml");

    if(!xmlfile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite ))
    {
     }

    QTextStream stream(&xmlfile);

    stream << result;
```

Comment: `but when i change the file extension to ".xml" it didn't create xml file. it just change extention` - are you kidding?
Look at e.g. [QXmlStreamWriter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qxmlstreamwriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
void writeXMLFile(){
    QFile xmlFile("xmlSample.xml");
    if (!xmlFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text ))
    {
        qDebug() << "Already opened or there is another issue";
        xmlFile.close();
    }
    QTextStream xmlContent(&xmlFile);

    QDomDocument document;

    //make the root element
    QDomElement root = document.createElement("StudentList");
    //add it to document
    document.appendChild(root);

    QDomElement student = document.createElement("student");
    student.setAttribute("id", "1");
    student.setAttribute("name", "Burak");
    student.setAttribute("number", "1111");
    root.appendChild(student);

    student = document.createElement("student");
    student.setAttribute("id", "2");
    student.setAttribute("name", "Hamdi");
    student.setAttribute("number", "2222");
    root.appendChild(student);

    student = document.createElement("student");
    student.setAttribute("id", "3");
    student.setAttribute("name", "TUFAN");
    student.setAttribute("number", "33333");
    root.appendChild(student);

    student = document.createElement("student");
    student.setAttribute("id", "4");
    student.setAttribute("name", "Thecodeprogram");
    student.setAttribute("number", "4444");
    root.appendChild(student);

    xmlContent << document.toString();
}}
```

Take a look at the official Qt documenation for more details: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomdocument.html

Comment: I'm trying to use QTextStream instead of QDomDocument. how can i do?

Comment: @bnyoo QtextStream here is also used. Did you mean QXmlStreamWriter? Take a look at the official documentation. If something from it is not clear - feel free to ask. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qxmlstreamwriter.html